# Fields of rows in CSV file not being seperated

Tags: python, csv, row

I'm trying to delete certain rows from a CSV file via Python(2.7). I want to delete those whose nth columns is "True".

However, my file only seems to have one column. I can access `row[0]` but that shows me all the entries in the row—it looks like this: `bla1;bla2;bla3;bla4`

This is my code so far:

```
import csv

with open('Mappe1.csv','rb') as inp, open('first_edit.csv', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if row[0] == "False":
            writer.writerow(row)
            print row[0]
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: use row.split(":")[0], this separates the line at every occurence of ':'

Comment: @LukasR - but OP claims this is a delimited text file so other considerations such as escaping the semicolon inside a cell may also be needed.

Comment: Fair enough, didn't consider this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the right delimiter character for the `reader` object. Set the delimiter character to `';'` to override the default `','`:

```
for row in csv.reader(inp, delimiter=';'):
    ...
```

Comment: @marakatrin You may consider accepting the answer if it helped.